# Arraylist java always give me the last value

Tags: java, arrays, arraylist

I spent all day with this problem. I populate an arrayList without problem but when I try to get the value I always recive the last value.

```
private List<double[]> marker;
double[] m= new double[3];    
double[] a= new double[3];    

....
marker= new ArrayList<double[]>();
for (int i=0;i<150;i++){

   int k = Math.abs(random.nextInt(10));
   int r = Math.abs(random.nextInt(10));
   int s = Math.abs(random.nextInt(10));

   m[0]=i;
   m[1]=46+(((double)k)*0.1)+(((double)r)*0.01)+(((double)s)*0.001);
   m[2]=9+(((double)r)*0.1)+(((double)s)*0.01)+(((double)k)*0.001);
   marker.add(m);
}
a=marker.get(5);
Log.i("Io","indice: "+a[0]+"lat: "+a[1]+"lon"+a[2]);
```

I always get the last "double[3]" that I added in the arrayList, why?

Answer (score 1):

you need to create object for each item. You only create one reference and they all use the same and update and you get the last updated value.

```
for (int i=0;i<150;i++){
    m= new double[3]; 
}
```

put object creation inside of the for loop

Comment: The object creation should be inside the loop but not THAT object creation. The marker list should not be created repeatedly.

Answer (score 1):

Because you are using the same array all the time, effectively overwriting its values over and over again.

You need to allocate a new array for each member of the list. Put the `new double[3]` inside the loop.